# Which Deal Should She Go For? Money

Tags: mathematics

```
Its coming up King Rat's birthday and for his birthday for he wants 20 rings.
So Queen Rat goes to a Ring Seller and he has 20.
He says: 'You can buy 20 rings for £1,000,000 or each ring doubles its value'.
Which deal should she go for?
```

**Qm:** To know why he wants 20, it's because he wants 10 for his fingers
and 10 for his toes.

Good Luck :)

**Hint:**

> Ring 1 is £1 and you would double it until you get the value of all 20 rings
> :3

Comment: The information on the cost of the first ring when buying them individually needs to be in the question itself, not in the hint. The question is unanswerable without that information. In fact the entirety of the information in the "hint" is either needed or just a clarification of the way individual rings are valued (and a badly phrased one at that).

Comment: Downvoting as this isn't a puzzle.  It's a simple math problem that can be solved with straightforward calculations.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, you should go for

> 20 rings for £1,000,000

Buying 20 rings, one by one will cost you

> 2^20-1 = £1,048,575. The individual rings will cost: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, for a total of £1,048,575.

Comment: +1 For Correct Answer. This is optional but if you would. Could you explain how?

Comment: @JamesMuir, explained.

Comment: You are Correct :)